# How to set cache to false on httpget from mvc4 controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-10, http-get

I have the following httpget that calls a controller action:

```
$.get('/Course/ExplanationCorrect/', postData, function (data) {
    $('#SurveyDiv').html(data);
});
```

This is working on all four other browsers but not on IE10 second pass through. I believe that this is a caching issue and I want to set cache to false. How can I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
$.get('/Course/ExplanationCorrect/', postData, function (data) {
        cache: false,
        $('#SurveyDiv').html(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this line of code will set the caching to false for all of your jQuery get requests

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
</script>
```

You can put that anywhere after your jQuery script tag

Alternatively, if you don't want to globally disable caching, you can use the following code for this request

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Course/ExplanationCorrect/',
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#SurveyDiv').html(data);
    }
});
```